# Как создать файл в заданной директории?

Tags: c

Нужна функция которая позволит создать файл в определённой директории. Например

```
"some_path/file.txt"
```

Проблема в том что директория может быть а может не быть. Если её нет то надо создать. Есть ли встроенная функция которая решает данную задачу?

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы создать файл, нужно сначала иметь директорию, в которой он будет располагаться. Если её нет, то надо её создать. При этом встроенной функции для создания директорий рекурсивно в [сишной библиотеке нет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2336242/3240681). Но довольно просто написать свою, например, вариант из упомянутого вопроса enSO:

```
static void _mkdir(const char *dir) {
    char tmp[256];
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t len;

    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp),"%s",dir);
    len = strlen(tmp);
    if(tmp[len - 1] == '/')
            tmp[len - 1] = 0;
    for(p = tmp + 1; *p; p++)
            if(*p == '/') {
                    *p = 0;
                    mkdir(tmp, S_IRWXU);
                    *p = '/';
            }
    mkdir(tmp, S_IRWXU);
}
```

Если речь о Windows, то [подойдёт функция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1530815/3240681) `SHCreateDirectoryEx`:

```
int createDirectoryRecursively( LPCTSTR path )
{
    return SHCreateDirectoryEx( NULL, path, NULL );
}

// ...
if ( createDirectoryRecursively( T("C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Baz") ) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
   // Bingo!
}
```

После того как директория создана уже можно приступать к созданию файла в ней любым доступным способом.